# Wrapping Blazor EditForm not updating Model

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly, blazor-editform

I want to wrap Blazor's `EditForm` component so that I can add some additional functionality.

Also, I'm creating input components that inherit from `InputBase<T>` for added features/functionality/ease of use.

When I use my custom inputs in Blazor's `EditForm`, the `Model` gets updated properly. However, when I use my wrapper for `EditForm`, the `Model` does not get updated. If I use Blazor's `InputText` component in my wrapper, the `Model` gets updated properly.

The code (edited for brevity):

BfForm.razor (the wrapper):

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms

<EditForm Model="Model" OnInvalidSubmit="OnInvalidSubmit" OnValidSubmit="OnValidSubmit" novalidate>
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
    <ValidationSummary />
    @ChildContent
</EditForm>

@code{
    //This displays the ChildContent as expected, validation works, but the Model does not get updated
    [EditorRequired, Parameter] public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }
    
    // When I use this, I get a .ToString(), i.e.
    // Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderFragment`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.EditContext]
    //[EditorRequired, Parameter] public RenderFragment<EditContext> ChildContent { get; set; }
    [EditorRequired, Parameter] public Object Model { get; set; }
    [EditorRequired, Parameter] public EventCallback OnInvalidSubmit { get; set; }
    [EditorRequired, Parameter] public EventCallback OnValidSubmit { get; set; }
}
```

BfText.razor:

```
@inherits InputBase<string>

@* I've tried using Microsoft's InputText with @bind-Value and @bind as well as @bind-value *@
<input 
    type="text"
    @attributes="AdditionalAttributes"
    @bind-value="CurrentValue" />

@code {
    protected override bool TryParseValueFromString(string value, out string result, out string validationErrorMessage)
    {
        result = value;
        validationErrorMessage = null;
        return true;
    }
}
```

And the usage:

```
<BfForm Model="model" OnInvalidSubmit="invalidSubmit" OnValidSubmit="validSubmit">

    <BfText DisplayName="First name" @bind-Value="model.FirstName" />

    @* When I use this, the Model does update *@
    <InputText @bind-Value="model.FirstName" />

    <p>fname: @model.FirstName</p>

    <input type="submit" />
</BfForm>
```

As mentioned in the comments, if I use `RenderFragment<EditContext>` in `BfForm.razor`, nothing gets rendered, instead I see ``` Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderFragment``1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.EditContext] ```.

However, if I use `RenderFragment`, the inputs get rendered, but the `Model` doesn't get updated.

And in `BfText.razor`, I've tried using Blazor's `InputText` component with the `@bind-Value` attribute, an html input element with both `@bind=` and `@bind-value` and the `Model` does not get updated in any cases.

Finally, when using my `BfForm` component, if I use Blazor's `InputText` component, the `Model` does indeed get updated.

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here. Since I'm inheriting from `InputBase<string>` seems like my `BfText` component should be grabbing the `EditForm`'s `CascadingValue`.

I've got the source code sitting in a class library on [github](https://github.com/Blazor-and-Friends/BootstrapFormComponents).

For convenience, here's the source code for [`EditForm`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Components/Web/src/Forms/EditForm.cs), [`InputBase`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Components/Web/src/Forms/InputBase.cs), and [`InputText`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Components/Web/src/Forms/InputText.cs)

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Why are you trying to pass the `EditContext` in the Render Fragment.  The `EditContext` is cascaded by `EditForm` so you don't need to try and do it yourself.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis Not sure what you mean. I did try to set the `ChildContent` on the `EditForm` directly in `OnParametersSet()`, didn't work. If I omit the render ( '@ChildContent' ) in `BfForm.razor`, nothing is rendered.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my attempt to simplify your code to help isolate the issue.  This code works, so what are you doing that's different?

#### MyInput.razor

```
@inherits InputBase<string>

<input 
    type="text" @attributes="AdditionalAttributes" @bind-value="CurrentValue" />

@code {
    protected override bool TryParseValueFromString(string? value, out string? result, out string validationErrorMessage)
    {
        result = value;
        validationErrorMessage = string.Empty;
        return true;
    }
}
```

#### MyForm.razor

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms

<EditForm Model="Model" OnInvalidSubmit="OnInvalidSubmit" OnValidSubmit="OnValidSubmit" novalidate>
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
    <ValidationSummary />
    @ChildContent
</EditForm>

@code{
    [EditorRequired, Parameter] public RenderFragment? ChildContent { get; set; }
    [EditorRequired, Parameter] public Object? Model { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public EventCallback OnInvalidSubmit { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public EventCallback OnValidSubmit { get; set; }
}
```

Index.razor

```
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h3>Index</h3>

<MyForm Model=model>
    <MyInputText @bind-Value=this.model.Value />
</MyForm>
<div class="p-2">
    Value: @model.Value
</div>

@code {
    private Model model = new();

    public class Model
    {
        public string? Value { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: This led to the problem. I fibbed with my code in an attempt to simplify it. I have an inheritance chain behind `BfText`, and in one of the base classes I was assigning an OnChange event without first checking if it has a delegate. Thanks!